# Maximum Numpy Array TypeError

Tags: python, numpy, max

Hey I have a simple numpy array with 7 columns, called data. I need the maximum of the second and last column, so I tried the following:

```
def intervall(data):
    start = np.amax(data[:,1])
    end = np.amax(data[:,6])
    return start, end
```

but for some reason I get this error:

```
TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), 1)' is an invalid key
```

Does somebody know why?

Comment: I think it should work if you use np.max not np.amax.

Comment: "Hey I have a simple numpy array with 7 columns" - that error message says you don't. You appear to have a Pandas DataFrame.

Comment: Ok, so I imported an xlsx file with pandas like this: def loadCSV(path, filename):
    data = dp.read_excel(path + '/' + filename, sheet_name=1, usecols=[0,1,3,5,7,9,11])
    data.to_numpy()
    return data[:].   I thought data.to_numpy() would turn it into an numpy array

Comment: `to_numpy` doesn't cause your DataFrame to become a NumPy array. It builds a new array that you promptly ignore and discard.

Comment: Also, a function that reads Excel files really shouldn't be called loadCSV.

Comment: Yeah, I copied it from a different project. Forgot to change the name :D

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you are actually using a `pandas.DataFrame`, in such a case you can use:

```
np.amax(data.iloc[:, [1,6]], 0)
```

i.e., selecting the columns `1` and `6` and specifying I want the maximum values for `axis = 0`.

---

For defining it as a function, you can do something like this:

```
def intervall(data):
    start, end = np.amax(data.iloc[:, [1,6]], 0)
    return start, end
```

---

If it were a `numpy.ndarray` you could do this:

```
np.amax(data[:, [1,6]], 0)
```

Comment: Now I get this error: TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), [1, 6])' is an invalid key

Comment: @vinc00 what does `type(data)` give you?

Comment: it says: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>, i guess thats the problem, do you know how i can turn it into a numpy array? I tried data.to_numpy() but I guess it doesn´t work

Comment: @vinc00 `data.values` gives you the numpy array